# Aggregate specific number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with many rows and I would like to consecutively aggregate say 10 rows and calculate the average of one column. So row 1 to 10 will be average value no. one, row 11 to 20 will be average value no. two, etc.

Can this be done in MySql?

Comment: Do you have an id or something like that? Put here the table schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to `GROUP BY FLOOR(something/10)` to group each 10 rows. A primary autoincrement key without gaps would be best for this.

```
SELECT FLOOR(something/10) as start_id, AVG(yourAmount)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY FLOOR(something/10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the ordering issue by using aliases and group/order by those in one simple query.

```
SELECT FLOOR(id/10) AS id_tmp, id AS sorter, AVG(col_1) AS col_1_avg 
FROM my_table
GROUP BY id_tmp
ORDER BY sorter DESC
```

I'm not sure why this works but in MySQL 5.0 it works anyway.